How to build python with custom openssl in windows
I have built the openssl module and I'm looking for command that could take my custom directory for building ssl modules like one in the linux.
sudo ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl --enable-optimizations `  
sudo make 
sudo make install

I ran this and here the -e installs external libraries from cpython bin, since there is only upto 3.0.13 tag i want to use a custom one, how to do this at ease or after building python can I swap the DLL's alone?
PCbuild\build.bat -e -d -p x64
